# Count All Pages And Get Latest Date In Python

Tags: python

I am working on a python script that reads 1000+ log files which are roughly 30GB in size. I open each file, check each line for a status (' 200 ') and get the *.aspx page which is called. I then count the amount of times the .aspx page match appears across all logs.

A new request has been asked that I also provide the latest date the page was accessed.

Here is the script I am currently running getting the counts...

```
def find_files(d):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(d):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith('.log'):
                yield os.path.join(root, filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    results = collections.defaultdict(int)
    status = ' 200 '

    for file_name in find_files('C:\\Test\\TestLogs\\'):
        with open(file_name, encoding="utf8", errors="ignore") as f:
            for line in f:
                if status in line:
                    line = line.lower().strip().replace('2f', '')
                    matches = re.findall('(\\w*.aspx\\b)(?!.*aspx\\b)', line)

                    if matches:
                        for word in matches:
                            results[word] += 1
    # print(results)
    with open('C:\\Test\\result.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        print('Filename:', str(results), file=f)
```

Here is an example of a log file...

```
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2023-01-02 04:01:17 3.2.4.3 GET /Admin/Login.aspx - 80 - 1.2.2.2 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/1.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://www.a.com/Finance/InvoiceAdministration.aspx 200 0 0 5
2023-01-15 04:01:20 3.2.4.3 GET /Finance/InvoiceAdministration.aspx - 80 test@test.com 1.2.2.2 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/1.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://www.a.com/Admin/Login.aspx 200 0 0 1644
2023-01-21 04:02:55 3.2.4.3 POST /Finance/InvoiceAdministration.aspx - 80 test@test.com 1.2.2.2 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/1.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://www.a.com/Finance/InvoiceAdministration.aspx 404 0 0 1029
2023-01-22 04:03:29 3.2.4.3 GET /Finance/InvoiceAdministration.aspx - 80 test@test.com 1.2.2.2 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/1.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://www.a.com/Finance/InvoiceAdministration.aspx 200 0 0 1621
2023-01-24 04:03:44 3.2.4.3 GET /Finance/InvoiceDetail.aspx - 80 test@test.com 1.2.2.2 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/1.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://www.a.com/Finance/InvoiceAdministration.aspx 200 0 0 306
2023-01-26 04:01:19 3.2.4.3 POST /Admin/Login.aspx - 80 - 1.2.2.2 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/1.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://www.a.com/Admin/Login.aspx 302 0 0 63
```

Here is the desired result based on the above example...

```
2023-01-24, 'InvoiceAdministration.aspx': 3
2023-01-15, 'Login.aspx': 1
```

I am struggling with working out how to get, check and append the date via the script I currently have. I am thinking I may have more success writing this using pandas? Any help would be appreciated. Even just a nudge with what approach might be best. Thank you!

Comment: Why aren't you counting `InvoiceDetail.aspx`? and `InvoiceAdministration.aspx` doesn't appear to have happened on `2023-01-24`. It's not clear how your desired results are related to the example log.

Comment: There are many, many existing packages that will extract statistics from Apache logs, and even display them with tables and graphs.

Comment: Your text processing is unnecessary.  Do a `.split()`; the date will be the first word,  the URL will be the 5th word, the status (200) will be word number -4.  You can pull the filename from the URL.

Comment: @Mark pages they wanted counted were the referred pages.

Comment: @TimRoberts any packages you can recommend? I tried logparser but it would crash when I try and run it. I'll look into this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Pandas` to process your IIS log files like CSV file:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

iis_cols = ['date', 'time', 's-ip', 'cs-method', 'cs-uri-stem', 'cs-uri-query',
            's-port', 'cs-username', 'c-ip', 'cs(User-Agent)', 'cs(Referer)',
            'sc-status', 'sc-substatus', 'sc-win32-status', 'time-taken']

def find_files(d):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(d):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith('.log'):
                yield os.path.join(root, filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = []

    for file_name in find_files('logs'):
        # Load log file as Pandas Dataframe
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None, names=iis_cols, sep=' ', comment='#')

        # Extract the script name /Admin/Login.aspx -> Login.aspx
        # (it's probably a bad idea if you have same name for multiple locations)
        df['script'] = df['cs-uri-stem'].str.split('/').str[-1]

        # Filter out your data: keep rows where status is 200 end script ends with '.aspx'
        m = df['sc-status'].eq(200) & df['script'].str.endswith('.aspx')

        # stats for the current file
        out = (df[m].groupby('script', as_index=False)
                    .agg(last_hit=('date', 'max'),
                         count=('script', 'size')))
        results.append(out)

    # Final output, merge all stats
    out = (pd.concat(results).groupby('script', as_index=False)
             .agg({'last_hit': 'max', 'count': 'sum'}))
    out.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                       script    last_hit  count
0  InvoiceAdministration.aspx  2023-01-22      2
1          InvoiceDetail.aspx  2023-01-24      1
2                  Login.aspx  2023-01-02      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache logs are very regular.  You can split then into words:

```
import collections
import os

def find_files(d):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(d):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith('.log'):
                yield os.path.join(root, filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = collections.defaultdict(int)
    status = ' 200 '

    for file_name in find_files('logs'):
        with open(file_name, encoding="utf8", errors="ignore") as f:
            for line in f:
                words = line.split()
                if words[-4] == '200':
                    date = words[0]
                    file = words[4].split('/')[-1]
                    results[date+'/'+file] += 1

    print(results)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'2023-01-02/Login.aspx': 1, '2023-01-15/InvoiceAdministration.aspx': 1, '2023-01-22/InvoiceAdministration.aspx': 1, '2023-01-24/InvoiceDetail.aspx': 1})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  The difficulty I am having is that I need to sum the page count and show the latest date the page appeared.  E.g...

2023-01-24, 'InvoiceAdministration.aspx': 3
2023-01-15, 'Login.aspx': 1